# How do modifiers effect function signatures?

Tags: solidity, signature, inheritance, modifiers, function-override

I want to change a function that my contract inherits to have a `modifier`, but are you allowed to add `modifiers` to overridden functions that didn't previously have a one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifiers don't have any effect on the function's `signature` so you can add `modifiers` to overridden functions without any problems.

The [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.20/abi-spec.html#function-selector) describes the function signature as:

> the canonical expression of the basic prototype without data location specifier, i.e. the function name with the parenthesised list of parameter types. Parameter types are split by a single comma — no spaces are used.

Here is an example contract that showcases a modifier being added to an overridden function:

```
contract Father {

    uint public number = 777;

    function foo(uint x, uint y) public virtual returns(uint) {
        number = x + y;
        return number;
}

}

contract Child is Father {

modifier mod() {
  _;
  if(number == 7) {
    number = 777;
  } 
}

function foo(uint x, uint y) public override mod returns(uint) {
        number = x + y;
        return number;
   }

}
```

In both contracts above, the `foo` function has the signature: `"foo(uint256,uint256)"`